# How do I make a professional slide show type video?

Tags: video-editor

My wife reads little kid books on YouTube like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_MSzhc0hz8). It displays each page in a scrolling pan as she reads it. Our video creator is not longer working with us, so I need to learn how to do it. She had a Mac. I have Windows 10. I'm a software developer, but I don't speak this jargon so I don't even know what to search for.

I need help.

Comment: This question is a bit broad. Are you asking what software you need, how to edit or do visual effects, or what the effect is called? The first question can be answered by searching this site for "free video editing software", the second is beyond the scope of a SE answer, and the answer to the third is "Ken Burns Effect".

Comment: I know it's broad. I didn't know where else to go. Thank you for your direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This video is very simple to do.

1. Record voice.
2. Use a proper camera/phone that takes high resolution images (so that when you zoom in the software, it will retain the quality), then take a photo of each page of the book.
3. Import images and sound into the software.
4. Do those effects in video which are basically (tilt, pan, zoom-in, zoom-out) mix between them and adjust speed accordingly.

**Note:** its always better to record sound first, and animate based on that, so that you know how long is each shot and when to cut. 
**What software:** Personally I only use After Effects and Premier Pro, they are not free but there is a Trial. Check this article for PAID and FREE editing software and try some of them: [The best video editing software 2018: paid and free](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-video-editing-software-paid-and-free)

Basically the effects/transitions mentioned above can be done with any of those softwares, a couple of tutorials should make it possible.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Filmora](https://filmora.wondershare.com/) for Windows. It seems affordable. The feature therein is called Pan and Zoom. This looks like it will work and be pretty easy.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that it was you who answered yourself. Kindly mark your answer and good luck.

Comment: @MEGA, Yeah, stib's comment helped me narrow my search. This is what I found. But I like your answer too. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad i could help somehow. all the best.

Comment: @MEGA, I have to say this was a way better experience that I had on stackoverflow the last few years. Thank you.